# Sorting data by the oldest date and color

Tags: excel, sorting

I'd want to sort a spreadsheet of data by the oldest "date" in column # 8, as well as by the color "Red" in column 1. I'm new to VBA and would greatly appreciate your assistance. I recorded the code below with a macro recorder, and it only works in newest Office (not 2010).

```
Sub SortData()

' Sort the PDR data

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("data").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("data").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("data").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "H2:H2848"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
        
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("data").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
        
    End With
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("data").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("data").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add(Range( _
        "A2:A2848"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color _
        = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("data").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
        
    End With
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  
End Sub
```

Comment: You may get some insight by searching on here, this is but one example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8920231/4961700

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I still need an example. Sorry for bothering you and thanks in advance.

Comment: That linkdoes contain an example and the answer may give you a better structure thatn what you show so far. You can search on here for others.

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("data").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("data").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "H2:H2848"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal